# Why does D compilation take so long?

Tags: compilation, d

D is one of the fastest programming languages to compile, if not the fastest, but this isn't always the case.  Things become painfully slow when `unittest` is turned on.  My current project has 6-7 modules (~2000 LOC), with every single one of them having unittests that also contain benchmarks.  Here are some numbers from my current project:

`dmd -O -noboundscheck` takes `0m1.287s`

`dmd -O -release -noboundscheck` takes `0m1.382s`

`dmd -O -inline -noboundscheck` takes `0m1.499s`

`dmd -O -inline -release -noboundscheck` takes `0m3.477s`

adding `-unittest` to any one of the above will drastically increase compilation time:

`dmd -O -inline -release -noboundscheck -unittest` takes `0m21.918s`

and sometimes it crashes DMD:

`time dmd -O t1.d -inline -noboundscheck -version=Double -unittest` takes `0m2.297s`
`Internal error: ../ztc/gdag.c 776`

Evidentially, unittest is buggy but at the same time it has become an important part of my project.  I would like to know if the slowdown is normal or is it something that's being worked on?  My project is growing and with every new unittest the compilation is taking longer and longer.  The only solution I know is to disable `-release` and `-inline`, but that's not always desirable.

Comment: Do you have many template instantiations in your unit tests?

Comment: @CyberShadow Yes, it's mostly template instantiations because there is a lot generic programming.

Comment: That's most likely the reason. Try moving the non-generic parts of your code outside the templates.

Comment: @CyberShadow there is no non-generic code.

Comment: @Arlen, I think he means try reducing the amount of generic code by only making the parts that are truly generic, generic. Often you can mitigate the problem by factoring out pieces of code from your templates that don't really have to be templated. It can also help even if you factor out such code into smaller templates that can be reused more often.

Comment: Yep. Compiler work per template = amount of code * total number of unique combinations of template parameters. Reducing work from either side will help.

Comment: Report that ICE, it isn't in the database yet (http://d.puremagic.com/issues/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ztc%2Fgdag.c)
You may want to use https://github.com/cybershadow/dustmite/wiki to do so.

Comment: Also it might be helpful if you profiled dmd and reported bottlenecks with unittest.

Comment: @CyberShadow I refactored my entire project and there is no more generic code; just plain Structs and functions.  Compilation still takes a long time (16s compared to 22s).

Comment: @Trass3r I've encountered two bugs that cause DMD to crash, but I can't bug report them because I can't isolate the issue.

Comment: @Arlen DustMite can't reduce it?

Answer (score 4):

DMD has a known issue with optimisations: [long blocks of code optimise with an O(n^2) algorithm](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7157), so long functions take a long time to compile with optimisations.

Try splitting your code up into smaller functions and you should get better compile times in the meantime. You can do this quite easily by using inline functions:

```
void foo()
{
    // lots of code
    // more code
}
```

Turn this into:

```
void foo()
{
    void block1()
    {
        // lots of code
    }
    block1();

    void block2()
    {
        // more code
    }
    block2();
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I think you mean nested functions?

Answer (score 1):

A very tiny performance improvement could be to move template instantiation to module-scope, via a `version(unittest) block`, e.g.:

```
auto foo(T)(T t) { return t; }

version(unittest) {
    alias foo!int fooInt;
}

unittest {
    auto x = fooInt(1);
}
```

Profiling this, I get around `~30msec` speed improvement if I use the aliased template instance in 5000 equivalent unittest blocks via `auto x = fooInt(1)`, compared to instantiating it directly in each unittest block via `auto x = foo(1)` (this actually expands to `auto x = foo!int(1)`).

This will likely only work for cases where you have a lot of unittests that create the same template instance.

Comment: templates or generic code doesn't seem to be the problem.  It does reduce compilation time, but overall it's not the issue.  I refactored my code and only noticed 4-6 seconds difference.  It's still very slow considering the fact that it's only 2k lines of code.  It has something to do with optimization.

Comment: Personally I don't use `-release` when unittesting. `-release- gets rid of any asserts that I might have which could make my unittests pass when they shouldn't.

Comment: @AndrejM. As long as you compile with `-unittest`, the assertions are not removed, even if you compile with `-release`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I did replace much of my generic code, but it only reduced compilation time by 4-5 seconds.  Things have gotten worse, and I believe the compiler is probably the issue:

`time dmd -O -inline -release -noboundscheck -unittest` takes `0m30.388s`

`time dmd -O -inline -release -noboundscheck` takes `0m11.597s`

`time dmd -inline -release -noboundscheck -unittest` takes `0m1.884s`

When `-O`, `-inline`, `-release`, and `-unittest` are all set, compilation takes the longest.  Dropping `-O` drastically reduces compilation time.  Therefore, to reduce compilation time while unittesting, drop the optimization flag(s).  For normal compilations, you could use either of the three (`-inline`, `-release`, `-unittest`) with no problem.  In my experience, it's the combination of all three that causes compilation to take the second longest, and the longest when `-unittest` is set as well.